# Named Query to delete a record by Supplying the entire object

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Hi I want to delete a record from the table spt_tutorials by giving an object of its entityClass SptTutorials .I am writing the named query like this.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "SptTutorials.deleteVideo", query = "DELETE s FROM SptTutorials s WHERE s.SptTutorials = :SptTutorials")})
```

where SptTutorials is the entity class and the parameter that I am passing thru the WHERE clause is a SptTutorials object.Is this query correct.

Comment: So SptTutorials has a field SptTutorials ?

Comment: No it is not a field, I was trying to match the entire object  SptTutorials

Answer (score 6):

As "SptTutorials" is **not** a field in SptTutorials then fix your query. "s.SptTutorials" means field "SptTutorials" of the object "s" (which is of type SptTutorials). Perhaps

```
DELETE FROM SptTutorials s WHERE s = :param
```

or

```
DELETE FROM SptTutorials s WHERE s.id = :id
```

Where "id" is the identity(field) of the SptTutorials object to be deleted.
All of that can be seen in a quick read of the JPA spec, or any of the many JPA docs online